# PC unable to find EXP_PDF.DLL

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, dll

I have an Excel workbook that uses VBA to create PDFs from sheets, and send them via email through Outlook.

When I click the button to create the PDFs and send, Microsoft Visual Basic gives me the follow error message:

> Compile error: Can't find project or library

The debugger then highlights the following code:

```
 Function Create_PDF_Sheet_Level_Names(NamedRange As String, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                                       OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String

    'This function will create a PDF with every sheet with
    'a sheet level name variable <NamedRange> in it

         Dim FileFormatstr As String
         Dim Fname As Variant
         Dim Ash As Worksheet
         Dim sh As Worksheet
         Dim ShArr() As String
         Dim s As Long
         Dim SheetLevelName As Name

         'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
         If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

...
```

In particular, the "Environ" in:

```
        'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
         If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then
```

It should be able to find EXP_PDF.dll, as it does exist at:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\EXP_PDF.DLL

The user is using Office 2007, so the correct corresponding folder is OFFICE12.

I have attempted to run Regsvr32.exe in order to register the dll, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://originaldll.com/file/exp_pdf.dll/12205.html) is a site with a solution for this problem

> Copy file exp_pdf.dll to the installation directory of the program
>   that is requesting exp_pdf.dll.   If that doesn't work, you will have
>   to copy exp_pdf.dll to your system directory. By default, this is:
>   Windows 95/98/Me - C:\Windows\System   Windows NT/2000 -
>   C:\WINNT\System32   Windows XP, Vista, 7 - C:\Windows\System32
>
> If you use a 64-bit version of Windows, you should also copy
>   exp_pdf.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
>
> Make a backup copy of the original files    Overwrite any existing
>   files    Reboot your computer.    If the problem still occurs, try the
>   following:    Open Windows Start menu and select "Run...".    Type CMD
>   and press Enter (or if you use Windows ME, type COMMAND)    Type
>   regsvr32 exp_pdf.dll and press Enter.
>
> If you can't find windows directory try the following:    Open
>   Windows Start menu and select "Run...".    Type CMD and press Enter
>   (or if you use Windows ME, type COMMAND)    Type %WINDIR% and press
>   Enter.

Comment: I've tried copying exp_pdf.dll to both C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12 and C:\Windows\System32, but to no avail.

I've also restarted the computer, and tried running regsvr32 again - but no luck. Regsvr32 gives me the following error message:

> The module "exp_pdf.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module cannot be found.

Comment: @AdamW - try running it like this: `%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 <full path of the DLL>`

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here, after Windows update. I fix it with an ' in front of the  If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles").... , another ' in front of Else and End If. Basically I eliminate that add in check. :)  For sure Microsoft changed the dll path or name together with the latest update, and I skiped this check.  Hope this will help.